# .xslm to .xslx using workbook.SaveAs() in Interop.Excel, executes with no issue but not saving the file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

Interop.Excel version 12

Office Excel 2007

I have worked on code to open .xslm file and then converting (saving) it as .xslx. Between this, I do need to do some processing as well but it doesn't matter. Following is the code:

```
namespace Exceltest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Application oXL = null;
            oXL = new Application();

            oXL.Visible = false;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

            try
            {
                Workbook book = oXL.Workbooks.Open("E:\\CorrectPF1.xlsm", 0, true, 5, "access123", "", true,
                                                   XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, null, XlCorruptLoad.xlNormalLoad);

                Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)book.Sheets["Resource allocation"];
                worksheet.Activate();

                oXL.Visible = false;
                oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

                book.SaveAs("E:\\PF1.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
                                            "", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                                XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, false);
            }
            catch (Exception  ex)
            {
             //Handling exception here
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This code executes with no issue (without any exception) but No file is saved with .xslx extension. I found it is working for some set of files but not others. Say, it is not working for file named PF1.xslm. I am able to open PF1.xslm in Office Excel and save it as .xslx. So, the same suppose to work programmatically as well.

Comment: Does the .xlsm file have macros in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save files with macros in it to .xlsx format. If you save a file yourself you should get an error message. I suspect the macro just gives up and doesn't save it, rather than displaying that error message.